# This should not be nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, entity-relationship, relationship, models

I have a simple test as such:

```
it "should create a post through a user for a blog." do
  @user.blogs.create(title: @blog.title)
  @user.blogs.find_by_title(@blog.title).posts.create(title: 'some title')
  post = Post.find_by_title('some title')
  post.title.should == 'some title'
end
```

This fails. Why? Because **we don't have any blogs for a user**. Ok lets throw a `binding.pry` in their:

```
it "should create a post through a user for a blog." do
  @user.blogs.create(title: @blog.title)
  binding.pry
  @user.blogs.find_by_title(@blog.title).posts.create(title: 'some title')
  post = Post.find_by_title('some title')
  post.title.should == 'some title'
end
```

Now that were in the console, lets see if `@user.blogs` gives us anything.

```
@user.blogs
=> [#<Blog id: nil, title: "user_blog_26">]
```

Ok .... But thats not the whole command. Lets see if @blogs has anything.

```
@blog
=> #<Blog id: 26, title: "user_blog_26">
```

Ok we are getting some where, we see that `@user` has the same blog associated to them. (although the id is missing in `@user.blogs` ... (**Note:** The relationship between users and blogs is: `User has_and_belongs_to_many :blogs, join_table: 'blogs_users'`)

So lets do:

```
@user.blogs.find_by(title: @blog.title)
=> nil
```

Um .....

Whats going on?

- **One**: My Blog association for a user doesn't have an id.
- **Two**: @user.blogs, returns all blogs for that user, but @user.blogs.find_by(title: @blog.title) returns nil? oO

Whats going on?

## Extra Info for the fun of it

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Promiscuous::Subscriber
  subscribe :first_name, :email, :user_name, :last_name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :blogs, join_table: 'blogs_users'
  has_many :posts, through: :blogs

  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i

end


class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Comment: Try to use `.build` instead of `.create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@blog
=> #<Blog id: 26, title: "user_blog_26">
```

`@blog` has an `id` assigned to it. So, that means its an existing record in `blogs` table with `id = 26`.

```
@user.blogs.create(title: @blog.title)
```

This line means that **create a new record in blogs table with title same as that of `@blog.title` (i.e., `user_blog_26`)**

Now, in `Blog` model you have

```
validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true ## title must be unique
```

A uniqueness check on the `title` field. So, obviously `@user.blogs.create(title: @blog.title)` failed as a record with title `user_blog_26` already exists in the `blogs` table (Recall @blog here). This is the reason why `@user.blogs` shows a blog with `id = nil` as the `associated blog` creation failed.

```
@user.blogs.find_by(title: @blog.title)
=> nil
```

As the `associated blog` with title `user_blog_26` was not created for `@user`. This query returns `nil`.

**Possible Solution**

You already have a `blog` record in the database referred by `@blog`. To assign that blog to your `@user`, simply update the example as below:

```
it "should create a post through a user for a blog." do
  @user.blogs << @blog ## This will set @blog.user_id = @user.id
  @user.blogs.find_by_title(@blog.title).posts.create(title: 'some title')
  post = Post.find_by_title('some title')
  post.title.should == 'some title'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When testing your code, you should have the test *isolated* form the world - they should not pass or fail because your real database has a row missing, or an unexpected row exist.

For that reason, you should use some kind of method where at the beginning of each test you *setup* the database to contain *only* what you need for the test, and at the end of the test you should *tear down* the database to prepare it for the next test.

There are a few gems out there which can help you with this strategy, such as [database cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner). Use one of those, and your tests will behave in a much more predictable manner.

Comment: My tests are perfect. They are the best. Don't comment.